# Text following a setext heading in a <pre> blocks is rendered in editor preview as non-pre-formatted text

Tags: bug, markdown, commonmark

I noticed that if one puts a [setext heading](https://spec.commonmark.org/current/#setext-headings) and some following text inside a <pre> block, the text following the setext heading gets rendered *in the editor preview* as non-pre-formatted text.

My intuition expected everything in the <pre> block to get rendered as pre-formatted text, but I'm not actually familiar with what the CommonMark spec says should happen here.

For example, here's some markup,

```markdown
<pre>
a setext heading
===
more pre-formatted text
</pre>
```

, which gets rendered *in the editor preview* like (approximately. I'm trying to replicate the appearance in the "final" post render because it only renders differently for the editor preview):

---

```
a setext heading
```


more pre-formatted text

---

In the rendering of the post (non-editor-preview render), it shows up properly:

```
a setext heading
===
more pre-formatted text
```

[Here's a sandbox link if you want to experiment more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385646/997587)

Comment: Without JavaScript (e.g., [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript)), the link redirects to the generic [https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/). It is an example of misuse of JavaScript. A non-broken link is [https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#setext-headings](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#setext-headings).